# How to get object that caused failure in Akka Streams?

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

According to [akka streams docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-error.html) one can handle stream failure by defining a decider that maps a `Throwable` to a `Strategy`:

```
val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case _: ArithmeticException => Supervision.Resume
  case _                      => Supervision.Stop
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to also get access to the element that caused the error. Of course, the type of this element is unknown, but is there a way to get it even as an instance of `Object`?

Comment: If there's an exception, there's no element. Exceptions are not caused by stream elements but by code. Where would an "error element" be in `Source.single(throw new Exception())` ?

Comment: That's true, but if I have a `Flow[Int, Int, ...]` there are `Ints` that are flowing through pipeline and I need to get to the element that caused the exception inside the flow.

Comment: I'm backing up @GiovanniCaporaletti. `Failures` are fundamentally different from `errors` - if your stream fails for some specific ints (like, it doesn't like number `42`), you could wrap the problematic stage with `try-catch` and inspect there; you can see the `Throwable` stack trace to learn which stage causes the trouble. A `Failure`, on the other hand, means the whole thing blew off and it is usually not connected to a single element (think external dependency crash, out of memory, etc.)

Comment: @Mihai238 maybe try to edit your question adding an example in which "an element causes an exception" and you cannot get "that element". You'll realize that there is no connection between the elements of the stream and the particular stage that threw an exception. 
Worst case we understand what you want to achieve and find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial way would be to catch the `ArithmeticException` near where it is thrown and throw your custom exception `MyDetailedArithmeticException(culprit: Int)` that would print the `int` that caused the problem in the message.